# Java: How to get only the return value of the method, but not repeat the prompt in the method?

Tags: java, methods, return-value

```
public class Year {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    getYear(keyboard);//asks year and takes it

    //Method to get the year from the user
    public static int getYear (Scanner keyboard) {
        int year;
        System.out.println("What year?");
        year = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (year < 1800 || year > 2300) {
            System.out.println("Invalid year. Please give valid year");
            year = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        return year;
    }
}
}
```

my code to get a year from the user. However I want to use the year that the user put in in other places. If I call the method, it repeats the prompt too. How can I just get the value of year outside the method?

Comment: 1. Remove the prompt (from within the method); 2. Possibly delegate the validation to  another method or callback

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I've understood your question but you can simply save the value returned from the `getYear()` method. Like this:

```
public class Year {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    int year = getYear(keyboard); //asks year and takes it
    
    System.out.println("Return value is: " + year);
}

//Method to get the year from the user
public static int getYear (Scanner keyboard) {
    int year;
    System.out.println("What year?");
    year = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (year < 1800 || year > 2300) {
        System.out.println("Invalid year. Please give valid year");
        year = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    return year;
}
}
```